# React Router Dom change URL on website load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

With React Router Dom, how can I change the URL of the website as soon as the site loads?

I have tried adding the following as an 'onLoadedMetadata' event on the main div for the nav, which loads on start.

```
 const loadHandler = () => {
    useHistory.push("./home");
  };
```

I also tried a similar method using 'useHistory.push("/home")' with use effect, and then triggering that when the location function from React Router Dom loads in. I wasn't able to achieve the result I'm looking for though.

I have set up the links and routes correctly, I just can't figure out how to make the URL change as soon as the website loads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect useEffect to `window.location.href="/example"` in your startup file (Probably `App.js`).

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.location.href="/example"
  });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I tried that too and it worked perfectly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Redirect` to redirect user to different routes.

Here `render` props with `Redirect` is used.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Route
    exact
     path="/"
     render={() => {
        return <Redirect to="/about" />;
     }}
  />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Using Just `Redirect`

```
<BrowserRouter>

  <Redirect from='/' to='/about' />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

[Simple Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-1iy3e?file=/index.js)

Comment: Hey, that worked perfectly, exactly what I wanted, thank you so much! Thanks for including the sandbox demo too, helped my understanding of it. Thank you! :)